# Can a role be granted roles+privileges in oracle all at the same time?

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle-12c, role

I know that you can grant a role:

- Other roles
- System privileges
- Object privileges

But, can you grant to the same role all at once? I mean, for example you grant a role:

- 2 roles
- 1 system privilege
- 1 object privilege

Is this possible?

If so, what is the priority of the grants? Are roles the top priority, or the privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can grant as many roles or privileges to a role as you want.
The order or priority does not matter because a role or privilege always permit something. Unlike for example Windows file permissions you don't have "allow write" and "forbid write" - where the priority/precedence matters.

Either the role gets a privilege or he does not.

However, you can create ROLES as use the ROLE as marker in PL/SQL at `DBMS_SESSION.IS_ROLE_ENABLED(...)`, there is would be possible to "restrict by granting" and the order and priority could matter. But such design would be quite ugly and is not recommended.

Comment: maybe I didn't understand your question, but I was referring to assigning roles and privileges to ROLES, not users. I don't if with roles you have the same scenario (if you can assign roles+privileges to an user) @Wernfried Domscheit

Comment: Yes, you can grant roles to other roles or grant roles to users. You can grant privileger to roles or users and you can mix all of them.